# glut.dll неправильно ложится на систему

Tags: windows, opengl

Запустил пример из книги Computer Graphics Through OpenGL: From Theory to Experiments, Second Edition (Sumanta Guha)  Первый урок . И мне комп сказал что нету библиотеки glut32.dll.

В общем решил решить эту проблему скачал и разархивировал glut32.dll ([от сюда](https://www.dll.ru/files/glut32-dll.html)) в папку C:\Windows\System32 прога вывела мне эту ошибку. Ложил библиотеку только в папку проекта, выпрыгивает та же ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом удалил библиотеку и положил её (64 битную версию) в C:\Windows\SysWOW64  но увы тот же самый результат .

Сейчас и в С:\Windows\System32 (32 битная версия), и в C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (64 битная версия) и добавил библиотеку glut64.dll в C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Что мне надо сделать, что бы решить эту проблему ? В чем моя ошибка ??

Comment: 0xC000007B = STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, так что проблема определенно в разрядности. Вы можете попробовать использовать Process Monitor, чтобы отследить, на какой именно DLL падает (это может быть не обязательно glut, а одна из ее зависимостей).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Папка `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` в 64-х разрядной системе предназначена для 32-х разрядных библиотек и приложений, а`C:\Windows\System32` - в основном для  для 64-х битных (т.е. эта папка при переходе на 64 бита осталась базовой для библиотек системной разрядности). Вот так, чтобы враг не прошёл :) [Случайная ссылка](https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/)

Так что, если ошибка связана с неправильной  разрядностью подключаемой библиотеки, то нужно ситуацию из предпоследнего абзаца поменять наоборот. Проверить, работоспособна ли связка приложение-библиотека проще, положив dll рядом с исполняемым файлом ([порядок поиска dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7d83bc18.aspx))